# Maintain object references when reading JSON file

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Is there a way to maintain object references when reading the JSON file in C#?

Let's say I have the following JSON text:

```
{
   "obj1":
         {
           "prop1": 1,
           "prop2":
                  [
                    {
                      "Id": 1,
                      "Name": "me"
                    },
                    {
                      "Id": 2,
                      "Name": "you"
                    }   
                  ]
         },
    "obj2": 
          [
            {
               "Id": 1,
               "Name": "me"
            }
         ]
}
```

I'd like to have member with `Id 1` under `prop2` to to refer to the same object as the one under `obj2` with `Id 1`. i.e. changing one have effect on the other.

**EDIT:**
I could use `PreserveReferencesHandling` setting, but my problem is i'm consuming the json so i don't have much control over the `SerializeObject` other than to re-`Serialize` it after i have read it. I was wondering if there is cheat to solve my problem. Otherwise I've thought of equating them after i've read them. i.e, after reading them i just say: `obj2[0] == obj1.prop2[0]`.

Comment: Two objects having the same reference?

Comment: atleast provide a proper `json`.

Comment: As you are using Json.NET, try [`PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveReferencesHandlingObject.htm).

Comment: See also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23453977/what-is-the-difference-between-preservereferenceshandling-and-referenceloophandl

Comment: @dbc that exactly what i want, but the problem is i'm consuming the json file so i don't have control over the Serialize part.

Comment: @rm - in that case I reckon equating them after you read them is easest.