# Using WebApi create Json format not in propery format

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-web-api

OutPut:

```
{
  "$id": "1",
  "_MenuList": [
    {
      "$id": "2",
      "parentId": 3,
      "menuName": "Details"
    },
    {
      "$id": "3",
      "parentId": 1,
      "menuName": "No of Details"
    }
  ]
}
```

In output "$id" autogenerate how to remove this.

Format Code Controller :

```
 [Route("MenuController/getMenuList/input")]
    [HttpPost]
    public ReportMenu getMenuList([FromBody]LoginModel input)
    {
        DataTable reportvalue = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection dataConnection = ConnectionString.getConnection())
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("USP_ReportMenu", dataConnection);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", input.userName);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", input.password);
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                using (SqlDataAdapter reportAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
                {

                    reportAdapter.Fill(reportvalue);

                }
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {

        }
        return getJson(reportvalue);

    }

public ReportMenu getJson(DataTable tb)
{
        ReportMenu menu = new ReportMenu();
        List<MenuModel> listMenu = new List<MenuModel>();
        for (int i = 0; i < tb.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            MenuModel obj=new MenuModel();
            obj.parentId = Convert.ToInt16(tb.Rows[i]["parentId"].ToString());
            obj.menuName = tb.Rows[i]["reportName"].ToString();
            listMenu.Add(obj);


        }

        menu._MenuList = listMenu;
        return menu;
    }
```

I want To this Type of ouput:

```
{"_MenuList": [
    {
      "parentId": 3,
      "menuName": "Details"
    },
    {
      "parentId": 1,
      "menuName": "No of Details"
    }
  ]
}
```

Kindly help for us.. I am new in Web API.

Comment: Post your related code.... There is nothing about json here

Comment: i had done in controller class which i done

Comment: This looks like your json serializer settings, without the code it's difficult to say: but check this out: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/23461179/4045532](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23461179/4045532)

Comment: I use JsonSerilizer class but auto generate $id which i don't  requried.

Comment: Can you provide the code where you setup your serializer?

Comment: In webApicofiguration.cs use
var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
            json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
            json.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

use this code

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments, what you'll need to do (as per the article I added in the comments) is replace:

```
json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
```

With this:

```
json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```

That will then ignore any reference handling, but you will get your desired result.