# Is it possible to configure Newtonsoft.Json to ignore propreties with [ScriptIgnore] attribute

Tags: json.net

I have a third-party class (lets call it `Class1`) which I need to serialize to JSON. If I try to do this as is, I either receive `StackOverflowException` or `JsonSerializationException` with message "*Self referencing loop detected with type*". I've tried to apply the following settings for the `JsonConvert` but it didn't help me to avoid `StackOverflowException`

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None,
    PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.None,
    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
};
```

After decompiling the `Class1` I found out that a lot of properties of the `Class1` are marked with `[ScriptIgnore]` attribute which is an analogue of `[JsonIgnore]` and is used by `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer` but I need to use Newtonsoft serializer.

As far as `Class1` is a third-party class I can't add `[JsonIgnore]` attribute to the needed properties.
I know that I can develop my own implementation of `IContractResolver`, and handle the problematic properties there, but I'd like to avoid this option.
Maybe there is a way somehow configure Newtonsoft serializer to take into consideration `[ScriptIgnore]` attribute as well as `[JsonIgnore]`. And do this configuration like it is done with `ReferenceLoopHandling`?

I would appreciate for any ideas.

Comment: There's no configuration option for this.  If you [search on github](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/search?q=ScriptIgnoreAttribute&unscoped_q=ScriptIgnoreAttribute), `ScriptIgnoreAttribute` doesn't even appear in the Json.NET source tree.   A [custom contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm#CustomIContractResolverExamples) is the way to go.  Should I make it an answer?

Comment: Also, can you explain why you don't want to implement a custom contract resolver?  It's actually really easy.

Comment: To make Json.Net respect `[ScriptIgnore]` the same as `[JsonIgnore]` can be done easily with a custom contract resolver as @dbc said.  It is just a few lines of code.  If you reject that solution out of hand, then the only other options I can think of would be forking and modifying the Json.Net source code to add support for the attribute, or mapping your `Class1` to a surrogate DTO class (or building up a JObject from it) and serializing that instead.

Comment: You could also try setting `PreserveReferencesHandling` to `Objects`; that should get rid of the `StackOverflowException` problem, but it will change the JSON output quite a bit.  See [What is the difference between PreserveReferencesHandling and ReferenceLoopHandling in Json.Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23453977/10263) for more details.

Comment: @BrianRogers , thank you, I've tried to use `Objects` as `PreserveReferencesHandling` but unfortunately without result, my issues still reproduces.

Comment: @dbc, @BrianRogers, thank you guys, I've already implemented my own `IContractResolver` and it's really not so big and complex. I think in my situation it's the best solution.

Comment: @dbc, yes, please make your option as answer, I'll vote for it

Answer (score 2):

There's no configuration option for this.  If you [search on github](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/search?q=ScriptIgnoreAttribute&unscoped_q=ScriptIgnoreAttribute), `ScriptIgnoreAttribute` doesn't even appear in the Json.NET source tree.

Even though you don't want to implement your own [`IContractResolver`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm#CustomIContractResolverExamples), this would be the straightforward solution and very easy.  First, define the following subclass of [`DefaultContractResolver`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver.htm) as follows:

```
public class ScriptIgnoreContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        if (!property.Ignored)
        {
            if (property.AttributeProvider.GetAttributes(true).Any(p => p.GetType().FullName == "System.Web.Script.Serialization.ScriptIgnoreAttribute"))
            {
                property.Ignored = true;
            }
        }
        return property;
    }
}
```

Then serialize as follows:

```
// Define a static member
static readonly IContractResolver myResolver = new ScriptIgnoreContractResolver();

// And use it in your serialization method
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = myResolver,
};
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rootObject, settings);
```

You may want to [cache the contract resolver for best performance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33557737/3744182).

Comment: My option is a little bit more compact:

`public class ScriptIgnoreCompatibleContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver

{

 protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
 {
  var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
  property.Ignored = member.GetCustomAttribute<ScriptIgnoreAttribute>() != null;

  return property;
 }

}`

maybe use it in the answer? Sorry for formatting, I can't format the code properly in the reply.

Comment: @AlexanderLysenko - I think I wanted to avoid needing to add a reference to `System.Web.Extensions.dll`, which is why I checked the type name.  But your way could reset `Ignored` from `true` to `false` if it had been ignored for some other reason.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Ok, now I see that my option has its cons, so just forget my comment :)